# ow to compute general processing time based on its complexity?

Tags: big-o

I'm really confused about this, how to compute general processing time based on its complexity?
the question is:
Let the algorithms A of complexity 0(n^1.5) and B of complexity 0(nlogn) process a list of 100 records for TA(100) = 1 and TB(100) = 20 microseconds, respectively. Find their processing time, TA(n) and TB(n), for n records and decide which of them will process faster a list of n = 100,000,000 records.
Anyone keen to help??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we can deal with A, It is similar to a quadratic and we must find a constant value of C with the initial conditions we are given; 1 microsecond (1e^-6 seconds, and 100 records.

Therefore

```
 1µ = C * 100^1.5

 1µ = 1e^-3 * 100^1.5

 C = 1e^-3
```

We can then substitute in the values of 100,000,000 records and the value we found for c.

This results in a time of 1,000,000,000µs or 1000 seconds.

Try and do this process with the second algorithm in order to tell which one computes the records faster.